# How to bcp from SQL server using Python to text file

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I am having problems with Using python with sqlserver.
I want to bcp out the results of sql query and save to a pipe delimited file.
Here's the code I have.

```
import pypyodbc

connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                'Server=testserver\dev01;'
                                'Database=mytestdb;'
                                'uid=testuser;pwd=readonly')
cursor = connection.cursor()

SQLCommand = "bcp SELECT * FROM mytestdb.dbo.testReports queryout ""C:/Users/PythonProjects/test.txt"" -Stestserver\dev01 -Utestuser -Preadonly -c -t|"
cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
result_set = cursor.fetchall()
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in result_set:
        f.write();
```

This is the error I get
 pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '/'.")

I am a newbie in python and need some help with this.

Thanks
MR

Comment: bcp is an executable - it is not a tsql function or command. If you are going to loop through a resultset and write it to a file in python, then there is no reason to attempt to invoke the bcp executable. Just select the rows directly - which is what your code is designed to do now. If you want to start a subprocess and run bcp, you should be able to find examples.

Comment: I want the columns "pipe" delimited text file that's why i am using bcp. there are 40 columns in the table.

Comment: Makes no difference. BCP is a program, not a tsql command and you are trying to use it as a tsql command. If you want to use bcp, go search -there are examples. But first, you need to define the correct parameters to pass to bcp - which you can do from the command line. I'll guarantee one thing - to pass a query as the source for bcp you need to delimit it properly. But your query does nothing special - just use the table as the source. You overcomplicate things.

Comment: got it. Used SQL query and then using csvwriter, specified delimiter. works like a charm. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows file paths are separated by backslashes in Windows apps like SQL Server, not forward slashes. Change those in your filepath.